# Visual explanation for the shape of $e^{2\pi i z}$

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, visualization

To be clear from the beginning, I am looking to develop my visual intuition for complex functions. I can explain *algebraically* why the plot below for $q(z) = e^{2\pi i z}$ looks the way it does, but I want to develop better intuitive reasoning with these complex contour plots.

With that out of the way... I have the following three complex plots, all generated in SageMath:

1. $e^z$

[image: plot of e^z]

2. $z^{2\pi i}$

[image: plot of z^{2\pi i}]

3. $e^{2\pi i z}$

[image: plot of e^{2\pi i z}]

Visually, it seems that the transformation from the first plot $(e^z)$, to the third $(e^{2\pi i z})$ is clear: the chart rotates 90 degrees clockwise, the period of the color strips moves from $2\pi i$ to $1$, and the transitions to both light and dark as are sped up as we move away from the origin.

Again, I can explain each of these pieces algebraically, but I'm not able to see why that happens from combining the first and second graphs. Of course the third is the plot of the composition $(e^{z})^{2\pi i}$, so somehow it should be applying the second transformation to the first plot.

**Does anyone have good enough intuition with complex plots to explain pictorially how we get the third from composing the first two?**

Comment: I have no idea what the colours in your plots are supposed to represent. I can't share any intuition with you if I don't understand what your pictures are telling us.

Comment: The colors indicate the angle of the output with red being 0, then going from 0 to 2pi i the colors are red -> green -> blue

Comment: Thanks. You should edit that information into your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the complex plane, multiplication by a unit modulus complex number encodes rotation about the origin through an angle equal to its argument. In particular, since $\arg i = \frac\pi2$, the map $z \mapsto iz$ rotates counterclockwise through a right angle. Now, multiplication by a real number scales the modulus of a complex number (stretches/shrinks it from the origin). These two operations commute, so it doesn't matter which you think of as happening first.

Putting this together,
$$
z \mapsto iz \mapsto 2\pi i z
$$
(1) rotates CCW by a right angle and (2) stretches by a factor of $2\pi$, so if $w = 2\pi i z$, then $w$ is a rotated and stretched version of $z$. Now, since this is happening in the input of the function $w \mapsto \exp w$, the effect on the graph is the inverse of this relationship, as usual. To wit, if $v = \exp w$ (and $w = 2\pi iz$), then for a particular $w$, the $z$ value that is fed into the exponential function is
$$
z = \frac{w}{2\pi i} = -i \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot w, 
$$
which is shrunk by a factor of $2\pi$ and rotated *back* (CW) by a right angle, so the colorful bands now stretch downward and are squeezed together. This is the value of $z$ that produces the particular output $v$, hence the pixel at this $z$ is colored according to $v$.

As an experiment, use some different scaling factors, e.g. $z \mapsto \exp(cz)$ with
$$
c = \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac12 \cdot \exp(-\tfrac\pi3), 
$$
should have colorful bands extending in $+60^\circ$ direction with double spacing.

Comment: The important thing to note is that it's much easier to think of the linear transformations happening *before* the application of the exponential function.

Comment: Great explanation. I would just add with regard to the intuitive explanation. You can split the term into a multiplication of real by complex value. The you may see that the imaginary part becomes a negative exponent in the "scaling" real part - this is demonstrated by the darkening (the signal is still there even though seems to be invisible) in the upper and brightness at the bottom. The real part of z becomes an imaginary, periodic function as visible from the coloring.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I agree that it is much easier to visualize what's happening if you think of $e^{2\pi i z}$ as $z \mapsto 2\pi i z \mapsto e^{2\pi i z}$, rather than $z \mapsto e^{z} \mapsto e^{2\pi i z}$, but I'm still curious if anyone has intuition on how to "read" the last plot as the composition of the first two. So I'm going to leave this open for a bit before accepting